# Roboto regular font face is rendered as bold

Tags: linux, windows, truetype-fonts, font-faces

I've installed the `Roboto` typeface on my system but it turns out that the default, `regular` face is rendered as `black`, even though in the thumbnail it appears to be lighter. This happens on all applications, on Linux and Windows too. Here's an example:

This is how the thumbnails look on any file manager on Linux, the fonts seem fine <s>(Windows doesn't even list the `regular` face on the collection)</s>. Windows only lists the `normal` face if I remove the `black` face:

[image: Roboto-Regular.ttf font thumbnail] [image: black face thumbnail] [image: Windows Black face thumbnail] [image: Roboto normal face thumb on windows]

And this is how it looks once it's rendered, no matter on what application:

[image: Roboto Regular face sample] [image: Black face sample]

[image: windows normal face sample] [image: Windows black face sample]

Any application that asks for the `Roboto` font, renders its `black` face instead. Google Chrome on Windows and Linux, side by side, for example:

[image: Google Chrome on Windows] [image: Google Chrome on Linux]

I've tried removing the `black` face <s>and symlinking to the `regular` one with the black's filename,</s> and it works (Windows and Linux result, side by side):

[image: Face removed linux] [image: face removed windows]

But I lose my black face and the italics are still rendered with the black face, so I'd have to remove the face along with its variants. What can I do? Is <s>symlinking</s> removing my fonts the only solution?

**Update**:

The problem is that both variants of the font (*regular* and *black*) interfere with each other, and I can only have one of the two installed at a time. Is there some sort of font *metadata* that I could change to fix this?

Comment: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/602/why-is-the-font-weight-bold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Google finally updated the Roboto font files on their website for download. You can grab the font here:
http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto

Answer (score 0):

Try the Windows naming:

- Regular: `roboto.ttf`
- Italic: `robotoi.ttf`
- Bold: `robotob.ttf` or `robotobd.ttf`
- Bold Italic: `robotobi.ttf` or `robotoz.ttf`
- Black: `robotobk.ttf`

Keep only these files. Remove the others and try again. I had a similar issue on Linux with `ttf-mscorefonts` (`arial.ttf`) and this solved the problem.

Comment: I've changed their names and they work fine except that now the black font is rendered as the regular one.